# How to populate a class with a C# String List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In the system I'm developing I send a select with multiple options to a string type list in my controller, I now need to link this list that I get from the view to the list with the login class I have in my model. The goal is that each position in the string list becomes a position in the new list.

For example I get the following list with the values that were sent from the view select:

[0] = "147"

[1] = "33"

I need to link this array to my other login list, something like this

Login[0] = "147

Login[1] = "33"

I'll put my codes with comments to explain it better:

View:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" asp-for="ListResponsibles">
    <option value="147">John</option>
    <option value="212">Maria</option>
    <option value="33">Luiza</option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
//Here I get the options marked in the select
public List<string>ListResponsibles { get; set; }

//I want to pass the list I received from the view to this list
public List<Responsibles> ListResponsiblesData { get; set; }
    
public class Responsibles
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterTask([FromForm] WebdeskTasks webdeskTasks)
{
//I created this variable to receive data from the other list
var LoginList = webdeskTasks.ListResponsiblesData;

//Here I tried to link each possibility of the view's list array to my list, but it doesn't show value in webdeskTarefas.ListResponsibles [i]
for (int i = 0; i < webdeskTasks.ListResponsibles.Count; i++)
{
    LoginList[i].Login = webdeskTasks.ListResponsibles[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or the LINQish way:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterTask([FromForm] WebdeskTasks webdeskTasks)
{
    webdeskTasks.ListResponsiblesData = webdeskTasks.ListResponsibles
        .Select(entry => new Responsible { Login = entry })
        .ToList();
        //....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is very nice solution, I will mark as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterTask([FromForm] WebdeskTasks webdeskTasks)
{
        var LoginList = new List<Responsibles>();
        foreach (string i in webdeskTasks.ListResponsibles)
        {
            Responsibles re = new Responsibles();
            re.Login = i;
            LoginList.Add(re);
        }
        webdeskTasks.ListResponsiblesData = LoginList;
        //....
}
```